# how to add filter to a queryset in django where the values come from the URL?

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
class ListPosts(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'posts/list_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'list_posts'

    def get_queryset(self):
        #kwargs={ "slug": user.slug }
        qs = Post.objects.all().filter(user=self.request.user)
        return qs
```

here the filter is added so the the queryset only filters the posts of the logged-in user.
My question is how can i show posts of the user's value coming from the slug in the URL

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w.@+-]+)/Posts/$', ListPosts.as_view(), name='user_posts'),
```

example:    `username/posts`
i know it can be done by passing kwargs from the URL. but how can i use two different models in the same view?

Comment: Check `request.GET()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to filter using slug value from URL. You can access it using self.kwargs dictionary. It can be done like this:

```
class ListPosts(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'posts/list_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'list_posts'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Post.objects.filter(
            user=self.request.user,
            some_field=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return qs
```

Comment: i get this error **Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field**  `qs = Post.objects.all().filter(user=self.request.user, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])`

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = Posts.objects.all().filter(user__slug__exact=self.kwargs['slug'])
    return qs
```

i found Django: invalid literal for int() with base 10">This to address the problem.

`Quote.objects.filter([model]__[field]__exact = [whatever])`